# Emulator slows down with each use

Tags: android, android-emulator

As i work in Android Studio 3.1.4, I have noticed that the Android emulator is blazing fast when I first open it.  As I continue to use it, typically by clicking on the "apply changes" icon, it slows down over time until it is eventually no longer usable.  If I then close the emulator and open it up again it reverts to being blazing fast.

This happens on multiple computers, all using Windows 10.  One of the PCs even has an SSD hard disk.  It happens in multiple apps, whether I have only one app open or multiple apps open.

Any thoughts about an easy fix for this?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why is doing that.I've heard about Genymotion emulator if you want to try(i haven't tried it yet though).You can give a try :)
[Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/plugins/)